# dispatch_once per app load or app lifetime?

Tags: macos

I've read that `dispatch_once` executes only once for the lifetime of the app. Does that mean that when you close the app and relaunch, the function won't be executed again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means once per process. If you quit the app and relaunch it and its code calls `dispatch_once()`, the block is executed.